# Who is this mysterious friend?

Tags: riddle

I am a keeper when I have a sibling,

I am a friend to a decision maker,

I am annoying at work,

I am scary in the forest.

Who am I?

HINT:

> Me and my sibling are 75% same

HINT 2:

> I like boxes

HINT 3:

> I am popular on Wall Street

HINT 4:

> I can be found in a travel document

HINT 5:

> I bite

HINT 6:

> In Russian, they call me 'little bird'

HINT 7:

> I can be found in all kinds of phallic objects

HINT 8:

> I am a comics superhero

HINT 9:

> BOOM

HINT 10:

> Check

FINAL HINT:

> Yes

Comment: I have modified the wording a bit, as the illiterate part was hijacking the focus (and could in fact be a subjective thing).

Comment: Perhaps it is time to add another hint or answer your own question.

Comment: I am running out of hints :) I will post an answer in an hour or so if nobody gets it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Final Answer**

> You are Tick.

I am scary in forest.

> Tick is a kind of insect found in forests. If it bites someone, he will die.

Sibling

> Right. Also Added by OP The sibling is tack or tock (3 of 4 letters are same). Tick-tack and tick-tock both refer to clocks which keep time. Also on the tick means being punctual.

Friend

> It is also friend of decision maker. As you take right decision, it will always be useful. Added by OP: Tick mark is a check mark. You put it in a box to say Yes (or no) to a decision.

At Work

> Added by OP: Nerve tick! Happens to the eye and causes it to twitch. Very annoying. Had it today ;) Usually sign of stress and looking at the computer too much

It also supports your hints.

Comment: You are being too philosophical :) The answer is simple.

Comment: @hypeJunction I have edited my answer check it.

Comment: You got it! It's the correct answer. Update the rest and I will upvote

Comment: I hope you enjoyed it. Was kind of obvious to me because I knew the answer :) I will come up with something else later.

Comment: Yes I enjoyed it a lot.

Comment: Nerve tick! Happens to the eye and causes it to twitch. Very annoying. Had it today ;) Usually sign of stress and looking at the computer too much.

Comment: The sibling is `tack` or `tock` (3 of 4 letters are same). Tick-tack and tick-tock both refer to clocks which keep time. Also `on the tick` means being punctual.

Comment: Tick mark is a check mark. You put it in a box to say Yes (or no) to a decision.

Comment: tick(et) and (s)tick are answers to two of the hints. Tick, tick... BOOM is a musical. Russian for tick is `птичка` - literally `little bird`

Answer (score 4):

> Sounds are annoying at the work place, scary in the forest, friends with the illiterate and a sibling to light. I do not know what it keeps, though

Comment: Nice guess,  but not the answer I am looking for

Comment: I have edited the riddle a little to make it simpler.

Comment: Keeper couild be an echo, his siblings are the sound over and over.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you are very close.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> doubt

Your sibling is

> fear

You are always with illiterates and decision makers.

At work, you are annoying.

In the forest, you are scary.

> You usually protect your owner against dangers. You are usually a safekeeping.

Comment: That's a logical answer but not what I am after.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Time

I am a keeper when I have a sibling,

> Timekeeper, if your sibling is running?

I am a friend to a decision maker,

> Time is needed to make decisions

I am annoying at work,

> You can't wait for work to end, right?

I am scary in the forest.

> Time spent in a dark forest can be scary

Comment: >! Quite warm on the keeper part. But not there yet on all others.

Comment: Meh, meta people, how do I create a spoiler in a comment?

Comment: Apparently, you can't. It's up to you to tell everyone, or no one if some hints are getting warm, because [*teamwork*](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2972/22184)

Comment: Well, there you have it, world wide web ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> Thoughts?

I am a keeper when I have a sibling,

> Thoughs always have a bit of the same objects in your mind.

I am a friend to a decision maker,

> Thoughts make decisions

I am annoying at work,

> Multiple thoughts can give you a hard time ( for example on some design)

I am scary in the forest.

> Thoughts of a murderer or bear walking around!

Hint 1:

> See, I am a keeper line

Hint 2:

> Thought boxes, thinking outside the box

Hint 3:

> What to buy?!

Hint 4:

> Not sure yet...

Hint 5:

> Thought bites

Hint 6:

> Little bird thoughs?

Hint 7:

> People's dirty mind and thoughs about phallic objects ;)

Comment: Only hint 4 I didn't get ...

Comment: Nice line of thinking. Got me chuckling. But no.

Comment: @hypeJunction damn :( close or not? :D

Comment: No, not even close.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear :D I'll keep searching then ;)